# Can I scrape data from an embed excel worksheet on my web page to send to my SQL Server database

Tags: html, sql-server, excel, post, embed

I am looking for solution to taking a template excel document and embedding it onto my website. After this users will use the template filling out certain cells. Is it possible for me to scrape a embedded excel sheet and use POST methods to send the data to my SQL Server database.

I want to embed the template because I need to change it from time to time, which means I love to have it easily changed within my code using the embed and iframe.

I have looked online and haven't found any solid documentation that this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you start by thinking about the differences between data in an Excel spreadsheet and data in a normalised SQL Server database.
For example, suppose you have a spreadsheet that you use to record downloads of "digital items" such as pdf files, word documents, .zip files, and so on.
Each column represents a date and each row represents a digital item.
So lest say Row 4 is for "The Cat Story.pdf" and Column 3 is for "15 February 2019. and Column 4 is for 16 February 2019 and so on. The value in Cell Row 4-Column 3 is "206", and the value in Cell Row 4-Column 4 is "327".

These two cells represent the following facts:
Fact 1: The pdf "Cat Story" was downloaded 206 times on 15 Feb 2019.
Fact 2: The pdf "Cat Story" was downloaded 327 times on 16 Feb 2019.

In an SQL Server database you could store such facts in a simple table called "Downloads" with Column 1=Item name, Column 2=Date and Column 3 = Number of downloads.

My longwinded explanation is to make it clear that in your case you are using an Excel spreadsheet as a tool to **display** data whereas the purpose of a well-designed  SQL Server database is to **store facts without any duplications.**

After you have decided on a normalised design for your SQL Server database, you can link your Excel spreadsheet directly to the data in your database.

Comment: Let me rephrase this question: I want to create a worksheet that users can fill out online, once they hit submit it will send the results to my data base (I have a well set up data base). This being said I like to use excel and embed it online in my website where users can fill out this worksheet/template. Is this a possibility? If so what is the best path to go down?

Comment: Yes, I did understand that you want to use Excel as a "data entry form" for SQL Server. And yes, it is possible to link Excel to an SQL Server database. (But many people would say: "Don't do it!"). Setting up the link is not so easy. You need to write an SQL Stored Procedure and then use Excel VBA to write a macro that maps the Excel's rows and columns into to your stored procedure.  (Bearing in mind that, as I explained,  your code must transform "Cells into Facts")  The help files of Excel and SQL Server contain all the detail on "How to". 
If I have helped, please vote on my answer.

Comment: I should also add that the typical way to display data from SQL Server on a website is to use the data grid controls in ASP.NET.